# How can i access elements in a iframe of a cordova WKWebview ios app?

Tags: ios, cordova, iframe, wkwebview

I want to access elements of our website that is embedded in a iframe of our ios App.
It has the same problem as file access.
SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "file://" from accessing a cross origin frame...

The file access problem is solved through this plugin https://github.com/globules-io/cordova-plugin-ios-xhr.
But access in a iframe is not solved.

How can i access elements in a iframe of a cordova WKWebview ios app?

Answer (score 0):

I've run into a similar issue in my Cordova apps with WkWebView.  You'll need to get the iframe to run under the "same-origin" of your app.  This is the only workaround I've found. It involves writing content directly to the iframe, rather than giving it a src="...". This way, iframe runs as same-origin as parent.  (Anything loaded via `src="file://..."` is treated as unique-origin in WkWebView, so blocks any cross-frame JavaScript.)

```
function frameEl_injectHtml(frameEl, injectHtml) {
    // frameEl must exist in DOM before its contentWindow is accessible.
    if (!frameEl.contentWindow) { alert("frameInjectHtml() but frameEl not (yet or anymore) in DOM."); return; }

    frameEl.contentWindow.document.open('text/htmlreplace');
    frameEl.contentWindow.document.write(injectHtml);
    frameEl.contentWindow.document.close();
}

// Create <frame>, insert into DOM, and inject content.
var frameHtml = "<html><head></head>" +
    "<body style='background-color:#eee; color:#000;'>" +
        "iframe body" +
        "<script>window.parent.alert('iframe even same-origin as parent.');</script>" +
    "</body></html>";
var frameEl = document.createElement('iframe');
frameEl.src = "about:blank";
document.body.appendChild(frameEl);
frameEl_injectHtml(frameEl, frameHtml);
```

You'll have to load the contents of the website pages somehow outside of this workaround, e.g. with an ajax call.